# How can i set onClickListener in Recyclerview only if status_id = 1 else no onClickListener

Tags: java, android, retrofit

After populating `json` data in `recyclerview` I want to set onclicklistener if `status_id = 1` else I don't want onclicklistener to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your onBindViewHolder

```
if(status.equals(1))
{
button.setClickable( true);
}
else
{
button.setClickable( false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make your onClick method and call it from your recycler click listener...

just see the example:-

```
 public  void onClicked(){
    if(id==1){
       //your code for listener
    }else{
       //do anything 
    }
```

then call it from your on click of recyclerview....see

```
 itemViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

               onClicked();

            }
        }
    });
```